# about functions in code that I don't know what they mean for what

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have been learning Vue.js, but I have come across something I do not understand. What does the following code mean: `_.`?

Comment: Perhaps it could be the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/) libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has no intrinsic meaning.

The underscore is just a character that is valid in JavaScript identifiers.

```js
const _ = {
  hello: function() {
    console.log("Hello!");
  }
};

_.hello();
```

The code you are looking at could assign any value to it.

It **might** be [the underscore library](https://underscorejs.org/). It **might** be [the lodash library](https://lodash.com/). It **might** be something else entirely.